# $\operatorname{div}(\vec{\nabla} \phi \times \vec{\nabla}\lambda) = 0$ using index notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

Let $\phi$,$\lambda$ be scalar fields

R.T.P $$\operatorname{div}(\vec{\nabla} \phi \times \vec{\nabla} \lambda) = 0$$ using index notation

what I had done was the following:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{div}(\vec{\nabla} \phi \times \vec{\nabla} \lambda) 
&= \operatorname{div} (\epsilon_{ijk} \cdot \vec{e_{i}} \cdot (\nabla \phi)_{j} \cdot (\nabla \lambda)_{k})\\
&= \operatorname{div}(\epsilon_{ijk} \cdot \vec{e_{i}} \cdot \phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k})\\
&= \operatorname{div}(\epsilon_{ijk} \cdot \phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k})\\
&= (\epsilon_{ijk} \cdot \phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k})_{,i}\\
&= \epsilon_{ijk,i} \cdot (\phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k}) + \epsilon_{ijk} \cdot (\phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k})_{,i}\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk} \cdot (\phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,k})_{,i}\\
&= \epsilon_{ijk} (\phi_{,ji} \cdot \lambda_{,k} + \phi_{,j} \cdot \lambda_{,ki} )
\end{align*}

from here I do not know how to proceed any further. is there an identity I could use?

Comment: Hint: symmetry of second derivative and antisymmetry of the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$.

Comment: but the indices of the second derivatives are different. one is ji the other is ki. that's where I'm lost symmetry usually works when one is ij and the other is ji.

Comment: Split the sum so you have $\varepsilon_{ijk}\phi_{,ji}\lambda_{,k}$ and $\varepsilon_{ijk}\phi_{,j}\lambda_{,ki}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot(\boldsymbol \nabla \phi \times \boldsymbol \nabla \lambda) &= \partial_i\left[\boldsymbol \nabla \phi \times \boldsymbol \nabla \lambda\right]_i \\&= \partial_i\Big(\varepsilon_{ijk}[\boldsymbol \nabla \phi]_j[\boldsymbol \nabla \lambda]_k\Big) \\
&= \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i(\partial_j \phi \partial_k \lambda) \\
&= \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j(\phi)\partial_k \lambda + \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \phi \partial_i\partial_k(\lambda).
\end{align*}
Then, \begin{alignat*}{2}
&\varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j(\phi) \partial_k \lambda \\
=& -\varepsilon_{jik} \partial_i \partial_j(\phi)\partial_k \lambda \quad &&\text{by swapping indices on $\varepsilon_{ijk}$}\\
= &-\varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \partial_i (\phi) \partial_k \lambda \quad && \text{by renaming dummy variables}\\
=& -\varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j (\phi) \partial_k \lambda. \quad &&\text{since mixed partial derivatives commute}
\end{alignat*}
Thus $\varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j(\phi) \partial_k \lambda=0$. More generally, this is because \begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j(\phi) \partial_k \lambda&= \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i[\boldsymbol \nabla \phi]_j [\boldsymbol \nabla \lambda]_k \\
&= [\boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \phi]_{k}  [\boldsymbol \nabla \lambda]_k \\
&= \boldsymbol \nabla \lambda \boldsymbol \cdot (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \phi),
\end{align*}
and the curl of a gradient is always $\mathbf 0$.

Similar operations on the other term prove the result.